# Is it possible to programmatically update a UILabel text that is updated within a function that is then called through a selector?

Tags: swift, xcode, uilabel, swift5

I currently have the following code where I would like to update the text of a label that appears after a button is clicked. I am unable to get the text to update according to a timer counter because I believe the UI label is not being updated in the main thread. However, I am unsure where to place `DispatchQueue.main.async()`. Because the `imglabel.text` variable is updated inside `imageButtonTap`, this creates a confusing situation since the function is called through `addTarget`. Does anyone have any ideas how I can get the text to update?

```
var counter = 0
var timer = Timer()    
var imglabel = UILabel()
class TaskViewController: UIViewController {
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(UpdateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            var imagesall = UIImage()
            let imagesView = UIButton()
            imagesView.setImage(imagesall, for: UIControl.State.normal)
            imagesView.addTarget(self, action:#selector(TaskViewController.imageButtonTap(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            self.view.addSubview(imagesView)
    }

       @objc func imageButtonTap(_ sender:TaskButton!) {
            let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: img_name))
            imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: sender.frame.size.width, height: sender.frame.size.height)
            self.imglabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: sender.frame.size.width, height: sender.frame.size.height)
            self.imglabel.clipsToBounds = true
            self.imglabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            self.imglabel.textAlignment = .center
            self.imglabel.text = String(self.counter)

            self.imglabel.center = imageView.center
            // Puts label on top of image. 
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.imglabel.bounds.size, false, 0)
            imageView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
            self.imglabel.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
            let imageWithText = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            sender.setImage(imageWithText, for: UIControl.State.normal)
            }

func timerAction() {
        counter += 1
        imglabel.text = "\(counter)"
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote code for your situation like below, hope this help

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var counter = 0
    var timer = Timer()
    var imglabel = UILabel()
    var button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 150, height: 50))
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "auricular-phone-symbol-in-a-circle"))
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        let imagesall = UIImage(named: "favorite-heart-button")
        button.setImage(imagesall, for: UIControl.State.normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.imageButtonTap(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(button)
    }

    @objc func imageButtonTap(_ sender:UIButton!) {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(timerAction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: sender.frame.size.width, height: sender.frame.size.height)
        self.imglabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: sender.frame.size.width, height: sender.frame.size.height)
        self.imglabel.clipsToBounds = true
        self.imglabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.imglabel.textAlignment = .center
        self.imglabel.text = String(self.counter)

        self.imglabel.center = imageView.center
    }

    @objc func timerAction() {
        self.counter += 1
        self.imglabel.text = "\(self.counter)"

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.imglabel.bounds.size, false, 0)
        imageView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        self.imglabel.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let imageWithText = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        button.setImage(imageWithText, for: UIControl.State.normal)
    }
}
```

The main things UILabel doesnt update bcz you render show text by using **UIGraphicsImageContext** but in update function you just update lable.text so it won't update text.

And 1 thing if i know correct, should put count timer when you click on the button, bcz when you create timer in viewDidLoad, if you stay 5s and then click button, this number will be 5 instead 0.

Answer (score 1):

You can add  `DispatchQueue.main.async` inside the action method. 
create a imagesView as a instance method instead of creating inside a vieDidLoad.

```
let imagesView = UIButton()
override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(UpdateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            var imagesall = UIImage()
            imagesView.setImage(imagesall, for: UIControl.State.normal)
            imagesView.addTarget(self, action:#selector(TaskViewController.imageButtonTap(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            self.view.addSubview(imagesView)
    }


@objc func imageButtonTap(_ sender:TaskButton!) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: img_name))
        imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: sender.frame.size.width, height: sender.frame.size.height)
        self.imglabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: sender.frame.size.width, height: sender.frame.size.height)
        self.imglabel.clipsToBounds = true
        self.imglabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.imglabel.textAlignment = .center
        self.imglabel.text = String(self.counter)

        self.imglabel.center = imageView.center
        // Puts label on top of image.
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.imglabel.bounds.size, false, 0)
        imageView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        self.imglabel.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let imageWithText = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        sender.setImage(imageWithText, for: UIControl.State.normal)
    }

}
```

Comment: Even after putting it inside the action method, the text still doesn't update. It appears to update only when I click on it, thus restarting the "cycle". Is `viewDidLoad` the right call?

Comment: add a breakpoint and check imageButtonTap is calling or not ?

Comment: Thanks, it appears that the label only updates if I perform a click. It seems that the image only updates if the tapgesture is done. Is the tapgesture perhaps overriding the natural updating?

Comment: where are you using the tapgesture ?